# Simplifying $6e^{i\pi/6}\times6e^{i\pi/4}$ to $a+bi$ form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, solution-verification

I am asked to express
$$6e^{i\pi/6}\times6e^{i\pi/4}$$
in the form $a + bi$.

If I use Euler's theorem, then $e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i \sin(z)$

$$6e^{i\pi/6}\times6e^{i\pi/4}=\left[\,6\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)+i6\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\,\right]
\times \left[6\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+i6\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right] \tag1$$

when I simplify I get
$$\frac{18\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}+\frac{18i\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{18i}{\sqrt2}-\frac{18}{\sqrt2} \tag2$$

which simplifies to
$$\frac{18\sqrt3-18}{\sqrt2}+i\left(\frac{18\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{18}{\sqrt2}\right) \tag3$$

Is this correct, or did I do something wrong?

Comment: It might be simpler to multiply in $re^{i\theta}$ form first, getting $36e^{5\pi i/12}$.

Comment: @robjohn are you suggesting that I take $36e^{5i\pi/12}$ and then using rulers theorem?

Comment: @meyou I think that’s exactly what robjohn is saying.

Answer (score 3):

Always make sure to consult a special trig ratios chart; there shouldn't be an irrational denominator anywhere in there. Your answer might be technically correct, but it's sloppy and not fully simplified.

$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \\
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}
\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

We can also clean this up by taking care of the real multiplication first. $$6e^{i\pi/6}\cdot6e^{i\pi/4}=36(e^{i\pi/6}\cdot e^{i\pi/4})$$ Then we have $$36(e^{i\pi/6}\cdot e^{i\pi/4})=36\left(\frac{\sqrt3+i}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt2i}{2}\right)=36\left(\frac{\sqrt6-\sqrt2}{4}+\frac{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}{4}i\right)=9(\sqrt6-\sqrt2)+9(\sqrt6+\sqrt2)i\text{.}$$

Normally, I would tell you to use your laws of exponents first to make it even easier, but $\dfrac{5\pi}{12}$ isn't an angle with a special trig ratio, so you're actually in the right for not simplifying that far right away.

Comment: Minor point: it should be $e^{i\pi/6}$ and $e^{i\pi/4}$.  Major point: $e^{i\pi/6}=\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac12i$.

Comment: @robjohn shouldnt it be $\frac{\sqrt3+i}{2}$?

Comment: @meyou: isn't that what I said? $\frac{\sqrt3+i}2=\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac12i$

Comment: @robjohn Ah, thank you. $\text{Fast typing}+\text{near bedtime}=\text{not my best work}$. It's been fixed with the correct calculation and answer.

Comment: I hope you don’t mind that I fixed one last typo.

Comment: @robjohn I welcome it.

Answer (score 0):

By using the polar form transformation, $$z=a+ib=re^{i\theta}=r(cos\theta + isin\theta)$$
Here $\theta$ can be defined as $arg(z)=tan^{\prime}(\frac{b}{a})$

Let $z_{1}=6e^{i\pi/6}=r_{1}e^{i\theta_{1}}$

This implies, $r_{1}=6$, and $arg(z_{1})=\theta_{1}=\pi/6$

Likewise, let $z_{2}=6e^{i\pi/4}=r_{2}e^{i\theta_{2}}$

This implies, $r_{2}=6$, and $arg(z_{2})=\theta_{2}=\pi/4$

It's clear that, $$z_{1}z_{2}=r_{1}e^{i\theta_{1}}. r_{2}e^{i\theta_{2}}=r_{1}r_{2}[e^{iarg(z_{1}z_{2})}]$$
It's clear-cut that,  $arg(z_{1}z_{2})=arg(z_{1})+arg(z_{2})=\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}$

This implies that, $$z_{1}z_{2}=r_{1}e^{i\theta_{1}}. r_{2}e^{i\theta_{2}}=r_{1}r_{2}[e^{iarg(z_{1}z_{2})}]=r_{1}r_{2}[e^{i(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2})}]$$
By substitution,  $$z_{1}z_{2}=r_{1}r_{2}[e^{i(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2})}]=36[e^{i(5\pi/12)}]$$
As we known that, $z=a+ib=re^{i\theta}=r(cos\theta + isin\theta)$

So that, $$z=a+ib=re^{i\theta}=36[e^{i(5\pi/12)}]=r(cos\theta + isin\theta)=36(cos(5\pi/12)+isin(5\pi/12))$$$$=9(\sqrt6-\sqrt2)+9(\sqrt6+\sqrt2)i$$

Comment: Thanks for clarification

Comment: anytime! Btw if the answer is helped you, may i ask you to tick that? thats just because i am new here, and i dont have permission to vote.